# Native Nuget Package Installs in VS But No Reference Added For C++ (Native) Projects

Tags: c++, nuget, native, nuget-package

I have just create a native Nuget Package(C/C++) and trying to consume it in another Native package in Visual Studio. From Nuget Package Manager, i am able to see that the  nuget gets installed and in package.config i am able to see it. But under project references it is still not referenced. How do i add the reference to the Native Nuget?

I have already tried updating the package.config as per the nuget versions but that didint help.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite unfortunate, but native Nugets are a thing of the past. VSPkg being developed by Microsoft is still in process and will probably be
released somewhere around 2020. CoApp provides a default way to create native C, C++ Nugets, but a lot of problems come with it. The `CoApp` project was ended
in its beta stage, so the support you get is only minimal and only from chat forums or IRCs.

Though `CoApp` is indeed a good tool to create native libraries/nugets, Nuget Package Manager by default creates a lot of problems for native nugets. The first 
and the foremost is referencing. 
Nugets by default use package manager to overcome this problem, but in case of native nugets in native projects, you don't get the choice. `ProjectReferences` are still a thing of the 
future for C++ projects and you are still bound to use the package.config to declare the versioning and references.

The Package Manager/CoApp creates native packages with a "/Native" tag also without any versioning. Thus without any versioning there is no way to reference the nugets in native projects.
The the only way to use native Nugets are either in `.Net Core` applications, in `Xamarin` or `C#` multitargeted projects that provide the above feature. It is quite unfortunate that C/C++ nugets cannot be used in C/C++ projects in VS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly add an native(C/C++) built nuget to a native (C/C++) project via Visual Studio. Well at
least not by default.
The only way to incorporate this is to load the Dll(and not nuget) at runtime. This seems to be the only way.
Well theres no point to add a C++ nuget to a C++ project anyways. It is better to add the references to the DLL.
just in case you dont want to, you might take the other option to load the DLL during runtime.
A very similar thing is done here:
https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/e4b9bd265c75704529409638fd9cdfac504a93ef/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/KestrelEngine.cs#L26